# How to do an n^2 search using any in python

Tags: python

How can I search whether there is an `a` in a list `X` such that there is a `b` later in the same list `X` such that the predicate `p(a,b)` returns explicitly true?

I.e. since `p` is a commutative function and potentially compute-intensive, if I have already called `p(a,b)`, then I wish to avoid calling `p(b,a)`.

Comment: sort the list and only call p(a,b) if a<b. Then you can avoid calling p(b,a) altogether

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the items in the list are not orderable.  There is no consistent way to sort them.

Answer (score 4):

[`itertools.combinations()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) produces a sequence of tuples without repeating:

```
any(p(a,b) for a,b in itertools.combinations(values, 2))
```

Comment: Could I use something like the following?
```
any(p(X[a],X[b]) for a in range(self.tds) for b in range(self.tds) if a > b)
```, the syntax is not correct.

Comment: @JimNewton you can, except it's `range(len(...))`, but it's not going to be faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can often define a custom class with a [`__lt__` comparator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__) to make an orderable type or a custom [`__hash__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) to make them hashable (must also define `__eq__`)

When creating your objects, make them instances of your custom type instead of whatever they normally are

```py
class OrderableCustomType(WhateverBaseType):

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.some_property < other.some_property
```

```py
class HashableCustomType(WhateverBaseType):

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.some_property == other.some_property

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.some_property)
```

You can use this to combine several properties into one comparison (for example both height and weight) and take the opportunity to cache expensive comparison calculations (for example if a network request is required)

Comment: I appreciate the comment;  however, I don't think forcing an unnatural order on an unorderable set is a good idea simply to avoid the question of how to handle a commutative function in an n^2 search.

Comment: I'd be surprised if you really had an incomparable set; if your arguments (or grossly, for example, their string equivalents) can at least be made hashable, you can [memoize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) the function inputs by decorating it with [`functools.cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cache)

Comment: The lists are lists of expression trees.  I could of course sort them alphabetically by their printable representation.   But again, that would be an arbitrary order which would change if I ever change the name of a class for example.   And it would require tree traversals to compute the print string.  It would be unnatural, and to me it would be asking for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I finally stumbled upon a solution.  I am supposing that python lists have constant time access into lists.

```
any(p(X[a],X[b]) for a in range(len(X)) for b in range(a,len(X)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want `any()` value in a collection of calculations, you can use `next()` to only calculate up to the first Truthy value

If the types are not hashable (though if you can arrange for them to be, your life will be easier!), you can keep the references in a list

Adapting [your Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68064511/4541045)

```py
try:
    value = next(a for a in range(len(X)) for b in range(a,len(X)) if p(X[a],X[b]))
except StopIteration:
    value = False
```